# my IF statement not working as expected

Tags: php, html

I have written a simplified example of my problem below:

```
<?php
    if($spType=="SPI") {
    ?><div id="mainImageInside">

    <?php echo $sSeries ?>

    <?phpif($sSeries ==4) {
    ?><div id="buDepth" class="font">worked</div><?php}?>

    </div><?php
    ;
?>
```

`$sSeries` is set to 3 so when I echo it I get 3 printed out on my screen, the if statement expects a 4 therefore this should not print out the text "worked" however, it does print the text "worked" no matter if the value is set as 3 or 4, could someone please help me with this?

Comment: what if you put a space between php and if?

Comment: Sorry for the mess, this was a quick test code, my real code is pages long therefore, I did not want to make it confusing

Comment: I see no closing bracket for the first if

Comment: You have not entered spaces and idents :) you have no `;` at the end of your echo statement.  You have an additional `;` .

Comment: Using curly braces for `if-else` clauses around raw HTML code is bad practice. The PHP parser hates carriages after it's closing tags when there's still code expected. It's better to use `<?php if (TRUE): ?> HTML CODE <?php endif; ?>`.

Comment: True, there's an additional `;` after `}` @AliMasudianPour . When closing `?>` you don't need `;`, it adds itself automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a million times more readable therfore easier to debug (for me at least)

```
<?php
if ($spType == "SPI") {

    echo '<div id="mainImageInside">' . $sSeries;

    if ($sSeries == 4 ) {
        echo '<div id="buDepth" class="font">worked</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Dagon, this will come in very handy when writing any future code.